# Get time in javascript like python time.time()

Tags: javascript

In python I can use `time.time()` to get this:

```
time = time.time()
time = 1362914221
```

How do I get this in java-script?

```
time = ????
```

Comment: A good question would have not been "like in Python" but would have specified what exactly was required (seconds since epoch for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like this:

```
var time = +new Date;
```

Comment: What does the `+new` syntax do here?

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
time = (new Date()).getTime() / 1000;
```

See [getTime() on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime).